# Is it possible to reverse a service pack on a Windows XP installation media?

Tags: windows, installation

I need to test a piece of code which only seems to fail on Windows XP RTM. Unfortunately, all my disks came slipstreamed with SP2 on-disk. Is there any way to install an RTM install using my SP2 CD and key?

Billy3
PS: Not sure if this belongs on SU or not -- please vote it over there if you think so.

Comment: @Close-voter: This is a development question. I'd not be trying to install hyper-old copies of XP to actually *use*.

Comment: I think that service Packs might be listed under "Control Panel" -> "Add/Remove Programs"; but perhaps not if they're pre-installed. Also when you install one you might be asked whether you want to preserve the old DLLs in case you want to install (answering "no" saves disks space).

Comment: @ChrisW: That's the problem -- SP2 is slipstreamed into all of my installation media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll need to find an RTM image somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an MSDN or TechNet subscription, you can download the original Windows XP image.

Comment: True, but 1. I don't and 2. that doesn't answer my question. :(